How do I estimate the standard deviation of the measured variables in linear regression?
Assuming a linear model:
$$
y = \alpha x + \beta
$$
I make n observations of $(x_i,y_i)$.
Each observation is subject to a measure uncertainty that I assume to be normally distributed with mean = 0 but unknown variance.
how do I estimate in Python $\alpha$, $\beta$ as well as $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$?
Here is some code that generates test data for the case $y = 2x + 1$:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import lstsq

n = 20
x = np.linspace(-5,5,n)
y = 2*x + 1

sigma_x = 0.1
sigma_y = 0.2

x_noisy = x + np.random.normal(0, sigma_x, x.shape)
y_noisy = y + np.random.normal(0, sigma_y, y.shape)

plt.plot(x,y, label = 'y = 2x + 1')
plt.scatter(x_noisy,y_noisy, color='red', label = 'Measured (x,y) values')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Given the x_noisy and y_noisy values above how can I recover $\alpha=2$, $\beta=1$, $\sigma_x = 0.1$ and $\sigma_y = 0.2$?

Perhaps $\alpha$ and $\beta$ could first be found by linear regression and next each measured point projected onto this line:

Next the standard deviations in x and y could be estimated from the distributions of dx and dy?

Your data do not permit you to analyze the error variance into a sum of a measurement variance and something else.  (Your model is said to be "unidentified.")  When you have repeated measurements of the same quantity, you can estimate the measurement variance and you're off and running.

@whuber: by repeated measurements of the same quantity do you in my case mean repeated measurements of y for a fixed x value?

Not just for a fixed value of $x:$ for exactly the same entity.  You need to isolate the measurement variability from all other forms of variability and measuring two different subjects with the same value of $x$ won't accomplish that. // There are models in which such replication is unnecessary--but the tradeoff is that your results depend on strong assumptions.  An example is assuming no "nugget effect" in Kriging, which permits you to estimate the measurement variance by extrapolating a variogram down to zero distance.

@whuber: are you saying that the observed variability from the line can not be decomposed into x and y variability as I suggest? Or in other terms: there is observed variability in measurements but how much of this variability is in x and how much is in y can not be determined? So this is similar to the problem x+y = 1, what is x and y?

That's exactly right.  All you can do with your model is estimate the total of the components of variability.

I'm not sure I totally understand what you are trying to do so forgive me if my comment is off topic. One thing that you could do under the assumption that x and y measure the same attribute (which I'm not sure is reasonable in your case) but with different amounts of noise/random error variance is to apply the model of essential tau-equivalence of classical test theory, which is identifiable for just 2 variables, where

I'm not sure I totally understand what you are trying to do so forgive me if my comment is off topic.
One thing that you could do under the assumption that x and y measure the same attribute (which I'm not sure is reasonable in your case), but with different amounts of noise/random error variance, is to apply the model of essential tau-equivalence of classical test theory, which is identifiable for just 2 variables. In the model,
y = a_y + t + e_y and
x = a_x + t + e_x,
where a = constant intercept, t = common true score variable with mean = 0, e = error variable with mean = 0, and cov(t, e) = 0.
In this model,
var(y) = var(t) + var(e_y) and
var(x) = var(t) + var(e_x),
since t and e are uncorrelated. The common true score variance is identified as var(t) = cov(x, y), the error variances are identified as var(e_y) = var(y) - cov(x, y) and var(e_x) = var(x) - cov(x, y), and the constant intercepts are identified as a_y = E(y) and a_x = E(x). The model parameters can be estimated through confirmatory factor analysis using, e.g., maximum likelihood estimation.
